# Django make_aware usage

Tags: python, django

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) says:

> The `pytz.NonExistentTimeError` exception is raised if you try to make
>   `value` aware during a DST transition such that the time never occurred
>   (when entering into DST). Setting `is_dst` to `True` or `False` will avoid
>   the exception by moving the hour backwards or forwards by 1
>   respectively. For example, `is_dst=True` would change a non-existent
>   time of 2:30 to 1:30 and `is_dst=False` would change the time to 3:30.

So I expect the time to be shifted one forward or backward depending on the value of `is_dst`.

But from my tests, the timezone is being shifted, not the time. Am I misunderstanding the Django docs or this is a bug ?

I tested the following :

```
import pytz
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 15 ,0 ,0)
print(make_aware(dt, tz))        # NonExistentTimeError
print(make_aware(dt, tz, True))  # 2017-10-15 00:00:00-02:00
print(make_aware(dt, tz, False)) # 2017-10-15 00:00:00-03:00
```

2017-10-15 is when DST will begin in that `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone, so when the clock reaches 00:00 it should jump to 01:00. The datetimes returned by the `make_aware` method are inexistent.

Comment: Just added the imports statements. `pytz` is [World Timezone Definitions for Python](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Huh. `make_aware` has a [different code-path for `pytz` timezones](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11b1/django/utils/timezone.py#L284)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.5/django/utils/timezone.py#L368) we can see that Django is just wrapping pytz. So if there's a problem here it's either a pytz bug or a Django documentation bug.

Now, since you're passing `localize()` a non-existent time, it's going to have to change either the wall-clock time or the `tzinfo` to return a valid time. Although the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) isn't very precise on this point, it appears that its contract is to always return a `datetime` with the same wall-clock time as what was passed in. That makes sense, especially when you consider the parallel case of an ambiguous time.

So I think the Django documentation is in error when it says:

> Setting `is_dst` to `True` or `False` will avoid the exception by moving the hour backwards or forwards by 1 respectively. For example, `is_dst=True` would change a non-existent time of 2:30 to 1:30 and `is_dst=False` would change the time to 3:30.

Note, though, that the actual moment in time is the same as what the documentation describes:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 15, 0)
dt_plus_one = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 15, 1)
dt_minus_one = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 14, 23)

make_aware(dt, tz, True) == make_aware(dt_minus_one, tz)  # True
make_aware(dt, tz, False) == make_aware(dt_plus_one, tz)  # True
```

Please consider [filing a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/) about this!

Comment: Kevin, thanks for you answer. Your tests made me understand how this method works. `make_naive` method shows the expected date and time. :)

Comment: If you or someone is interested, there is a discussion regarding this behavior on a Django plugin PR [here](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/634)